# Using the Javascript SDK, how can I obtain a Facebook user id, when the user has not yet authorized my application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Right now I am able to detect a user's login state using the Javascript SDK getLoginStatus method. In a case where a user has not authorized my application, as expected, I get the following response:

authResponse: null, status: "not_authorized"

I would like to access the publicly available information for the logged in user via the graph api(https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID). My goal is to display something that just says "Hello (person's name), click here to connect to our facebook application!", or something along those lines. Is there a way to get the user ID of a logged in user who has not yet authorized your application?

Thanks

Comment: What type of app is this? Canvas, tab or connect app?

Comment: Make them authorize app before entering it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a way to get the user ID of a logged in user who has not yet authorized your application ?

No, there's no way of getting user id without authorising your app.